# when is _declspec( novtable ) unsafe?

Tags: c++, vtable

Under what circumstances will `_declspec( novtable )` cause an access violation?

For example, this code doesn't:

```
class __declspec(novtable) Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { };
    virtual int Foo() const = 0;
    virtual int Bar() const { return 2; };
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    int Foo() const { return 1; };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    A a;
    volatile int a1 = a.Foo();
    volatile int a2 = a.Bar();

    Base* c = new A();
    volatile int c1 = c->Foo();
    volatile int c2 = c->Bar();
    delete c;

    return 0;
}
```

This code also does not:

```
class __declspec(novtable) Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() { };
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    Base a;
}
```

But, this code will:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{ 
    Base* a = new Base();
    delete a; // access violation
}
```

Why does the code in the first two example not throw on the destructors?

Comment: Any virtual member with an implementation is unsafe.  You can use `__interface` instead of class to get the compiler to enforce this.

Comment: @Hans Passant - Fancy! I did not know about that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k13k85ky%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
>
> If you attempt to instantiate a class marked with novtable and then
>   access a class member, you will receive an access violation (AV).

The code where you get an access violation is the code where you're explicitly calling "delete" on the novtable class.

Comment: That makes sense, but why don't I also get one when `Base a;` goes out of scope in the second example?

Comment: The behavior is undefined. "Seeming to work" is valid undefined behavior. (The technical reason is that the object type is fully known so the vtable lookup can be optimized away. An optimization masked a bug.)

Comment: Using this novtable on a class without any virtual function could produce any issue?